# find names of table who is in the same department sql

Tags: sql

I was asked during an interview about this SQL question.

---

Given Employee table

```
LastName    DepartmentID
Rafferty    31
Jones       33
Heisenberg  33
Robinson    34
Smith       34
Daniel      34
Williams    NULL
```

and Department table

```
DepartmentID    DepartmentName
31              Sales
33              Engineering
34              Clerical
35              Marketing
```

How could I find ALL of the employees who is at the same department as 'Robinson'? (through a generic way)

Is join (inner join) something that he wanted me to do?

Comment: `IN`, `JOIN`, `EXISTS`, `=` . . . There are lots of ways to express this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN`:

```
select *
from employee
where departmentId in (
        select departmentId
        from employee
        where LastName = 'Robinson'
        );
```

Using `JOIN`:

```
select e.*
from employee e
join (
    select distinct departmentId
    from employee
    where LastName = 'Robinson'
    ) e2 on e1.departmentId = e2.departmentId;
```

Comment: Thanks! really appreciate that!